# Auto duplicate and protect sheet except for some cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to all of this but am helping friends with a sheet to automate their checkout in their restaurant.

I have built up a sheet that will need to be duplicated each day, and I would like to have the sheet automatically protected upon duplication with the exception of some cells that their staff can edit.

I know that I need to do this in script, but am not sure of where to start. The unprotected cells will be: B6:F12, C3, and K13.

Answer (score 1):

## Duplicate and Protect Sheet with some Unprotected Ranges

```
function duplicateProtectSheet(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Source').activate();
  var sh1=ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var r1=sh1.getRange('B6:F12');
  var r2=sh1.getRange('C3');
  var r3=sh1.getRange('K13');
  sh1.protect().setUnprotectedRanges([r1,r2,r3]);
}
```

""References**

- [Protection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [SetUnProtectedRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setUnprotectedRanges(Range))
- [Sheet Protect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect())
- [Duplicate Active Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#duplicateActiveSheet())